# How to exclude captcha field from admin custom user change

Tags: django, django-forms, django-admin

forms.py

```
class UserChangeForm(UserChangeForm):
    captcha = CaptchaField()
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = '__all__'
```

admin.py

```
class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    add_form = UserCreationForm
    form = UserChangeForm
    model = User
    readonly_fields = ['created_at', 'updated_at']
    ordering = ('email',)
    exclude = ('username',)
    list_display= [
        'email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'middle_name', 'email', 'is_staff',
        'is_active', 'date_joined', 'role', 'phone',
        'convenient_time', 'status', 'created_at', 'updated_at',
        ]
    fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'fields': ('password', 'captcha')
        }),
        ('Personal info', {
            'fields': ('first_name', 'last_name', 'middle_name', 'email')
        }),
        ('Permissions', {
            'fields': (
                'is_active', 'is_staff', 'is_superuser',
                'groups', 'user_permissions'
                )
        }),
        # ('Important dates', {
        #     'fields': ('last_login', 'date_joined') #no need to change dated for user
        # }),
        ('Additional info', {
            'fields': ('role', 'phone',
        'convenient_time', 'status', 'created_at', 'updated_at')
        })
    )
    add_fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'fields': ('password1', 'password2')
        }),
        ('Personal info', {
            'fields': ('first_name', 'last_name', 'middle_name', 'email')
        }),
        ('Permissions', {
            'fields': (
                'is_active', 'is_staff', 'is_superuser',
                'groups', 'user_permissions'
                )
        }),
        ('Additional info', {
            'fields': ('role', 'phone',
        'convenient_time', 'status')
        })
    )
```

I need captcha from field in view ONLY not need it in admin.
exclude = ('username', 'captcha') cause "please correct the error below.".
If I add captcha to fieldset and fill it form saves succesfully.

Want to exclude captcha field from admin panel